# Моделирование бизнес процессов

Tags: erwin, case

Посоветуйте freeware аналог пакета ERWin Proces Modeller (ранее BPWin). Например, freeware аналог ERWin Data Modeller - Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Designer в составе Oracle Developer Suit 10g доступен на [сайте](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/101202winsoft-087370.html) для скачивания бесплатно.

Comment: Он простенький и имеет массу недостатков, но юзабелен достаточно, чтобы можно было использовать для работы.

Answer (score -1):

знаю trial - http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/

когда истечет срок можно дату на компе назад переводить =) ну или купить.
и в Eclipse, кажется, есть плагин для workflow, но я его не нашел